# How do I determine the number and order of ligand orbitals?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, transition-metals, symmetry

I am trying to create interaction diagrams for transition metal species by reducing the representations for both $\sigma$ and $\pi$ ligand orbital sets and mixing them with the metal orbitals. The order of metal orbitals is obvious because I know I have my 5 degenerate $n\text{d}$ orbitals, then my $(n+1)\text{s}$ orbital, which is higher in energy due to its principal quantum number, then my $(n+1)\text{p}$ orbital, which is higher in energy due to penetration (it's a p orbital); and the number of metal orbitals is apparent because my character table lists the each representation's matching function, so I can tell $\mathrm{A}_{1g}$ will have s-symmetry and $\mathrm{E}_g$ will match my $\mathrm{d}_{x^2-y^2}$ and my $\mathrm{d}_{z^2}$ orbitals, for example.

I don't see exactly how I should do the same for my ligand orbitals, though. For example, I know that my ligand $\pi$ orbital irreducible representation is $\Gamma_{\pi} = \mathrm{T}_{1g} + \mathrm{T}_{2g} + \mathrm{T}_{1u} + \mathrm{T}_{2u}$, and I know from my table's matching function list that there will be three $\mathrm{T}_{1u}$ $(x,y,z)$ and three $\mathrm{T}_{2g}$ $(xy, xz, yz)$ orbitals, but I don't know how to identify that there are also three $\mathrm{T}_{1g}$ and $\mathrm{T}_{2u}$ orbitals, since my character table doesn't list the matching functions for those representations.

Also; my understanding of how to decide on the ligand orbitals' relative energy levels is dubious. Yves Jean's *Molecular Orbitals of Transition Metal Complexes* says "one must analyze the bonding or antibonding character" (p. 43), but I am not getting it right every time. Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: Are you looking at the Oh group character table as it does contain the T1g and T2u representations?

Comment: yeah of course. It just doesn't have a matching function next to them, so I was unsure of how to figure out how many orbitals from my ligand set match those symmetry representations. This is also a more general question, though, but that's a good example of my problem.

Comment: T refers to triply degenerate set, E refers to doubly degenerate set, A and B are singly degenerate. The total number of orbitals should add up to the total number of atomic orbitals on your ligands.

Comment: Oh, OK that actually answers my question.

Comment: I understand that the total number of orbitals should add up to the total number of AOs, but I didn't realize the thing about T, E, A, B. For that matter, I'm also a little unsure about 1, 2, g and u.

Comment: 1, 2, g, and u don't refer to degeneracy, but to symmetry of the irrep with respect to one of the operations. u/g is (anti)symmetric wrt inversion.  B/A is (anti)symmetric wrt to rotation around the principal axis. To the best of my knowledge, 1/2 differentiate between mirror planes.

Comment: Are you asking about how to find the irreps of the ligand pi-type orbitals? In general you would have to construct a reducible representation for all the relevant orbitals (by investigating how they transform under the symmetry operations of the $O_\mathrm{h}$ point group), and then reduce this into a sum of irreducible representations. The matching functions column can only help you so much here, unfortunately!

Comment: orthocresol, I already did that. My reduction yielded Γπ=T1g+T2g+T1u+T2u . I was asking how I know how many degenerate orbitals come from T1g and T2u. I know that T2g and T1u have three each and I need 12 in total (it's pi orbitals on a D4h square planar molecule), but I was unsure about the other two, but V. Vladimirov told me that T representations necessarily refer to triply degenerate sets of orbitals.

Comment: The other element of my question was how to find the energetic order of those orbital sets, but as I understand it, you need to create the interaction diagram beforehand for that, because it's based on the bonding/antibonding nature of the orbital overlaps each one contributes to.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. As for the energetic ordering, if your only desire is to construct a qualitative MO diagram, I would say that you can just treat them as having the same energy. This is because the overlap between the different orbitals is poor (not least because they are far away from each other) and so any bonding/antibonding effects will be small. However, if you do want to figure it out, you will have to work out which linear combinations correspond to which irrep, and look at the bonding/antibonding interactions within these linear combinations.

Comment: got it. I'm more concerned about getting the number right. The energy order is just a detail. Based on what V. Vladimirov said about T=triply degenerate, E=doubly, etc., my problem is solved.

Comment: @V.Vladimirov I'd encourage you to write that up into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T refers to triply degenerate set, E refers to doubly degenerate set, A and B are singly degenerate. The total number of orbitals should add up to the total number of atomic orbitals on your ligands. 1,2,g,u are symmetry labels (look up Mulliken symbols). One thing to remember when constructing you MO diagram is that only orbitals of similar energy and the exact same type and symmetry can mix. So, you can only mix A with A, B with B, E with E and T with T. Also, only g with g, u with u, 1 with 1 and 2 with 2.